# ExtJS4: from which class to derive?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm working on custom component, which will contain combo and displayfield. It's supposed to be a combobox with validation message next to it. 
I'm wondering, from which base class to derive that one in order to have such functionality like store binding ect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found that it can be a simple Ext.panel.Panel.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use standard ExtJs validation mechanism? It will produce exact outcome you want - a label next to the combobox.

Comment: Actually, no. It can render an icon next to combo, or a label under. And I need a label on the right.